# How to associate text field and checkbox in angular form

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angularjs-directive

So i have dynamic form fields in angular form which get added on button click but now i want to add a checkbox infront of each text filed. Since i am new to angular i am facing difficuty in implementing it.Currently i have this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xweja5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html can someone please help me out associating a checkbox with input field.It might be simple thing but i am not able to figure it out have been trying it from past 1 day. Any help if greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the checkbox do?

Comment: @Arcteezy its captures the boolean value related to input field ie if that input is global field or not

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. What do you mean by global field?

Comment: @Arcteezy treat as additional information associated with input field

Comment: Can you do template driven forms? If would be easier to combine inputs into groups.

Comment: @Arcteezy can we have dynamic fields in template form? also can you suggest me how can i get it working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xweja5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html here is whats currently working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204480/discussion-between-yogesh-manjhi-and-arcteezy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

**template.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <button type="button" (click)="onAddProduct()">Add Product</button>
            <div formArrayName="productList" *ngFor="let item of productList?.controls; let i = index">
              <div [formGroupName]="i">
                  <label for="">Your row</label>
                  <input formControlName="name">
                  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="selected">
                  <button (click)="removeProduct(group.value,i)">remove</button>
              </div>
            </div>
{{myForm?.value|json}}
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  public myForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [],
      productList: this.fb.array([])
    })
  } 

  onAddProduct(group:FormGroup) {
    const creds = this.myForm.controls.productList as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.fb.group({
      name: [''],
      selected:[''] 
    }));
  }

  get productList()
  {
    return this.myForm.get('productList') as FormArray;
  }
  removeProduct(group:FormGroup,index:number)
  {
    (group.get('productList') as FormArray).removeAt(index)
  }


}
```

here is working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-from-array-demo?file=src/app/app.module.ts)